# How to get citation count?

Tags: web-scraping

I have an academic question. I have number of papers in [ACM](http://www.acm.org/) and [IEEE Explorer](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/guesthome.jsp).

I want to get the citation count of those papers programatically, and integrate into our project page.

Are there any tools around to achieve this?

Comment: You could consider using ['Beautiful Soup'](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 0):

The best tool that I have come across is:

http://jsoup.org/

Especially if you are familiar with css selectors.

Another great tool is:

http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/

If you explain the problems that you are encountering in a bit more details I could possibly help more!